# Unable to add transition when width of navbar is changed with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, nav

I have a navbar in with I am changing the width when the checkbox is clicked. When the checkbox is clicked, I want the navbar to smoothly transit to the larger width. It seems to be working only the first time on the snippet.

Here is the code I have:

```js
function change() {
  var nav = document.getElementById("navbar");
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("checkbox");
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    nav.style.width = "300px";
  } else {
    nav.style.width = "fit-content";
  }
}
```

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 0.3s;
  box-shadow: rgba(136, 165, 191, 0.26) 4px 2px 10px 0px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) -4px -2px 16px 0px;
}

nav input {
  margin: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <input onclick="change()" type="checkbox" name="" id="checkbox">
  <p>Home</p>
</nav>
```

Comment: `transition` will only work if you increase the width of your navbar in `%` or `px`.  For example; `initial-width: 300px` and width after transition `new-width: 100%` or any `x%`, x`px`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A transition only works on numeric values, so you need to change the width in the else-case accordingly, for example to 50px.

```js
function change(){
    var nav = document.getElementById("navbar");
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("checkbox");

    if(checkBox.checked == true){
        nav.style.width = "300px";


    } else{
        nav.style.width = "50px";
   
    }
}
```

```css
nav{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width:100px;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 0.3s;
    box-shadow: rgba(136, 165, 191, 0.26) 4px 2px 10px 0px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) -4px -2px 16px 0px;
}

nav input{
    margin: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  
        <input onclick="change()" type="checkbox" name="" id="checkbox">
        
       <p>Home</p>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `checkbox` with JavaScript you can use `onClick` event listener on navbar. And then create a class for example `.expanded` and toggle class accordingly.

```js
const navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');

navbar.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  navbar.classList.toggle('expanded');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: white;
  transition: width 250ms ease;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.navbar.expanded {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <p>Navbar</p>
</nav>
```

Hope it will work